what does this mean when you pray for something not to happen, but still that thing happen in a big way?
Whenever I pray to Allah swt to make things good and make a particular thing easy for me and solve the issue in a better way, then only after few days something bad happens about that issue. Else it gets more worst or it becomes impossible for me or for my family to tackle it.

Prayer is only a request to Allah, whether Allah gives it you or not is Allah's decision. But when you pray to Allah, you are assured of one of the 3 things as mentioned in the following hadith

It was narrated from Abu Sa’eed that the Prophet (peace and blessings
of Allah be upon him) said: “There is no Muslim who does not offer any
du’aa’ in which there is no sin or severing of family ties but Allah
will give him one of three things in return: either He will answer his
du’aa’ sooner, or he will store it up for him in the Hereafter, or He
will divert an equivalent evil away from him because of it.” They
said: “We will say a lot of du’aa’.” He said: “Allah is more
generous.” Narrated by Ahmad (10749)

